# ImmutableJS filter results without key, returning object

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have this following data structure as an ImmutableJS `Map()`:

```
{
  kXTy9K7XdzfJ73H7N: {
    _id: 'kXTy9K7XdzfJ73H7N',
    username: 'john'
  },
  Tx7aW2xw3nF3QCFhA: {
    _id: 'Tx7aW2xw3nF3QCFhA',
    username: 'oliver'
  }
}
```

I also have this key: `kXTy9K7XdzfJ73H7N`, which I’d like to remove from the map so all that’s left is:

```
{
  _id: 'Tx7aW2xw3nF3QCFhA',
  username: 'oliver'
}
```

I’ve already tried a combinated of `filterNot` and `mapKeys` but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
users.find((v, k) => k !== 'kXTy9K7XdzfJ73H7N')
```

Or you could change up your current approach:

```
users.delete('kXTy9K7XdzfJ73H7N').first()
```

The [first()](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/first) method comes from `Iterable`, so there's no need to convert your map to a list using `toList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by…

```
users.delete('kXTy9K7XdzfJ73H7N').toList().first()
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant way, so do say if there’s a better solution.